# How Can I control the nunmber of tabs raws inAndroid 1.5

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I'd like to divide my tabs to 3 diffrent raws so each raw will have tabs of a similar activity( E.g. action games, board games, shooters games)
How it can be done?
Thanks,
Eyal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "raw" you mean "row", you cannot have tabs spanning multiple rows -- sorry!